# ip-10-100-28-20 login: [ 17.201999] overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'

Tags: login, aws, overlayfs

Ubuntu 22.04 running on an AWS instance which is shutdown most evenings and restarted in the morning. Has been running without issue for @6 months

Failed to start this morning with the error as shown:
ip-10-100-28-20 login: [   17.201999] overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
AFAIK nothing has changed since the last successful start.

Detached the vDisk and attached to a recovery instance, start instance and mounted the vDisk
Plenty of diskspace available (its not using LVM) - only @7Gb of 32Gb used.

Web searches pointed towards docker as a possibility, so removed the links for start on boot
Reattached the vDisk and rebooted - same error.

I am in the process of enabling password authentication (currently only ssh), but not confident this will improve things.

Any thoughts ?

Many thanks